# How to send form data to Gmail without using nodemailer

Tags: node.js, npm, html-email, nodemailer, contact-form

I was trying to get form data to my gmail account so I get to know about 'nodemailer' package but the problem is that it is asking for my gmail password also I have to make my gmail account less secure for this.
Is there any way to get mail without my password?

Comment: create one test gmail account and use it

Comment: @indraraj26 I don't want to use gmail password. What's the point for making a test gmail account?

Comment: So that you can use the test account to email to your real account. Note that nodemailer cannot put email into **your own** Gmail account. It can only use your gmail account to email to **other people's** email account

Answer (score 0):

Use an 'App Password' for this purpose. This is "a 16-digit passcode that gives a less secure app or device permission to access your Google Account". See https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en